# ошибка в WebPack

Tags: javascript, node.js, frontend, webpack

```
    C:\Work\prohabits-ui-html>webpack
YError: Too many arguments provided. Expected max 2 but received 3.
    at module.exports (C:\Users\Aleksandr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yargs\lib\argsert.js:31:13)
    at Object.Yargs.self.alias (C:\Users\Aleksandr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yargs\yargs.js:244:5)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\Aleksandr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\bin\config-yargs.js:12:4)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Aleksandr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js:22:26)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
C:\Work\prohabits-ui-html\webpack.config.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import webpack from 'webpack';
                                                              ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at requireConfig (C:\Users\Aleksandr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\bin\convert-argv.js:96:18)
    at C:\Users\Aleksandr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\bin\convert-argv.js:109:17
```

Файлы не мои, прислали проект и не могу запустить. Модули все установил. В чем собственно ошибка вижу, но не хватает знаний что бы устранить. Где искать ошибку? Спасибо.

Comment: `npm update` делали, если нет, сделайте должно попустить )))

Comment: @Shnur спасибо за ответ, но не помогло.

Comment: Хм, а может просто версия ноды настолько старая, что не умеет в импорт?

Comment: какая версия webpack?

Answer (score 0):

В файле webpack.config.js нужно заменить

```
import webpack from 'webpack';
```

на

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
```

т.к. динамическая загрузка нативных модулей запрещена.
Похоже предыдущий разработчик прогонял конфигурации через транспайлер.

Answer (score 0):

Что бы у вас заработал webpack с es6 модулями, надо назвать конфиг `webpack.config.babel.js` и в конфиг импортировать `import 'babel-register'`, ссылка на babel-register, https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-register